# Cube colored in opengl es 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to draw a cube using OpenGL 2.0 on android. However, it's seem not work right. This is the result

[image]

and this is my code

Cube.java

```
package com.example.android.opengl;

 /**
 * Created by duykq57hotmail.com on 3/6/2016.
 */

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

 /**
 * A two-dimensional triangle for use as a drawn object in OpenGL ES 2.0.
 */
public class Cube {

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                //"attribute vec4 aColor;" +
                //"uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                //"  vColor = aColor;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
private final int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static final int COLORS_PER_VERTEX = 4;
static float triangleCoords[] = {
        // Front face
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

        // Right face
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

        // Back face
        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

        // Left face
        -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

        // Top face
        -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

        // Bottom face
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
};
float color[] = { 0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,

        // right, blue
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,

        // back, also green
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,
        0f, 0.5273f, 0.2656f, 1.0f,

        // left, also blue
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.3398f, 0.9023f, 1.0f,

        // top, red
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,

        // bottom, also red
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f,
        0.8359375f,  0.17578125f,  0.125f, 1.0f, };
private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex
private final int colorStride = COLORS_PER_VERTEX*4;


/**
 * Sets up the drawing object data for use in an OpenGL ES context.
 */
public Cube() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            triangleCoords.length * 4);
    // use the device hardware's native byte order
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
    vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
    // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    vertexBuffer.position(0);


    ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            color.length * 4);
    // use the device hardware's native byte order
    bb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
    colorBuffer = bb2.asFloatBuffer();
    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
    colorBuffer.put(color);
    // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    colorBuffer.position(0);



    // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
    int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program

    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables

}

/**
 * Encapsulates the OpenGL ES instructions for drawing this shape.
 *
 * @param mvpMatrix - The Model View Project matrix in which to draw
 * this shape.
 */
public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, vertexBuffer);

    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
//        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aColor");
//        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
//        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
//                mColorHandle, COLORS_PER_VERTEX,
//                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
//                0, colorBuffer);

    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");


    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}

}
```

MyGLRenderer.java

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.example.android.opengl;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Provides drawing instructions for a GLSurfaceView object. This class
 * must override the OpenGL ES drawing lifecycle methods:
 * <ul>
 *   <li>{@link android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer#onSurfaceCreated}</li>
 *   <li>{@link android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer#onDrawFrame}</li>
 *   <li>{@link android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer#onSurfaceChanged}</li>
 * </ul>
 */
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGLRenderer";
    private Triangle mTriangle;
    private Square   mSquare;

    // mMVPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

    private float mAngle;
    private Cube mCube;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {

        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        mTriangle = new Triangle();
        mSquare   = new Square();
        mCube = new Cube();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        float[] scratch = new float[16];

        // Draw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 2, 2, -6, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        // Draw square
        //mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        mCube.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        // Create a rotation for the triangle

        // Use the following code to generate constant rotation.
        // Leave this code out when using TouchEvents.
        // long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
        // float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);

        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, 1.0f);

        // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
        // Note that the mMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
        // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

        // Draw triangle
        //mTriangle.draw(scratch);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
        // such as screen rotation
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width / height;

        // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
        // in the onDrawFrame() method
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

    }

    /**
     * Utility method for compiling a OpenGL shader.
     *
     * <p><strong>Note:</strong> When developing shaders, use the checkGlError()
     * method to debug shader coding errors.</p>
     *
     * @param type - Vertex or fragment shader type.
     * @param shaderCode - String containing the shader code.
     * @return - Returns an id for the shader.
     */
    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }

    /**
    * Utility method for debugging OpenGL calls. Provide the name of the call
    * just after making it:
    *
    * <pre>
    * mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    * MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");</pre>
    *
    * If the operation is not successful, the check throws an error.
    *
    * @param glOperation - Name of the OpenGL call to check.
    */
    public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, glOperation + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the rotation angle of the triangle shape (mTriangle).
     *
     * @return - A float representing the rotation angle.
     */
    public float getAngle() {
        return mAngle;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the rotation angle of the triangle shape (mTriangle).
     */
    public void setAngle(float angle) {
        mAngle = angle;
    }

}
```

Could you help me solve this problem? Thank you very much

Comment: Which output do you expect? You are looking from (1,1,-6) into the orgin, and see the "back" face of your cube. To me, this looks like exactly how it should look.

Comment: Thank for your help. But my cube is only green. The others face of cube are the same. Can you help me. Sorry because of my bad English

Comment: you'll never see any other face of your cube with your current code, so how can you know that?

Comment: I tried to change the view @@. I edited my image above with looking at (2,2,-6)

Comment: Well, you are using a uniform value as color, and never specify your color array as vertex attributes (nor does your shader expect them), so the code still behaves as expected

Comment: @derhass: thank for your help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you want each face of the cube to be a different colour.

In your code, `vColor` is a uniform.  This means that every point on your cube will have the same colour value.

You need to pass in `vColor` as an attribute to your vertex shader, and then pass it on to your fragment shader as a varying.

Your shader code should be something like this

**Vertex shader**

```
attribute vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 vColorVarying;

void main() {
 // other shader code ...

  vColorVarying = vColor;
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
varying vec4 vColorVarying;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColorVarying;
}
```